# Dropbox api upload file

Tags: python, api, upload, dropbox

I'm trying to upload a 'txt' file to dropbox with python API.
After looking everywhere I know I found nothing that works, or I just don't understand how to make it work.

```
with open('Hello.txt') as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f,'/PythonClass/data_src')
```

I have also tried this:

```
with open('Hello.txt') as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), folder_py_src, mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
```

and this:

```
with open('Hello.txt', "rb") as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), folder_py_src, mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
```

I'm getting an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\pytask\classprojectdropbox", line 46, in <module>
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), folder_py_src, mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))     
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dropbox\base.py", line 2931, in files_upload
    r = self.request(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dropbox\dropbox_client.py", line 348, in request
    raise ApiError(res.request_id,
dropbox.exceptions.ApiError: ApiError('2d7014d399964557a8658a49ae90ef75', UploadError('path', UploadWriteFailed(reason=WriteError('conflict', WriteConflictError('folder', None)), upload_session_id='pid_upload_session:TOKEN')))
```

Comment: Does changing it to `with open("Hello.txt", "rb") as f:` help?

Comment: I tried that too, did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `f` parameter for [`files_upload`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_upload) expects `bytes`, so you should make sure you both open the file as binary (`"rb"`) and then `read` the data out, like this:

```
with open('Hello.txt', "rb") as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), folder_py_src, mode=WriteMode('overwrite'))
```

Comment: I have tried it before. it doesn't work for me as well. i added the full error i get

Comment: My answer was for the original "TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type, got <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>" error you posted.  I was able to reproduce that error, and was able to resolve it with the version of the code I posted. I see you've edited your post with a different error now though.

Comment: The new 'path/conflict/folder' error you posted indicates that the upload failed because there's already a folder at the specified path. You'll need to specify a `path` that doesn't point to a folder itself. Note that your `path` value should include the filename you want as well, e.g., like `"/folder/file.ext"`, not just `"/folder"`.

Comment: I love you! i cant believe that was the issue, thank you for your time i appreciate it.